# Angular 4 unittest coverage not 100% due to contructor

Tags: angular, unit-testing, code-coverage

I noticed that my coverage from my Angular 4 project is not 100% due to problems with the constructor. I'm using the default angular-cli setup. At the coverage report it shows that the constructor is called 19 times in total, but it still is marked as untested. Therefore not all branches are tested.

Does my code have any problems in it? Is there a bug in the coverage report?

My code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestService } from '../shared/request.service';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileService {

    private customerType;
    private profiles;
    private features;

    constructor(private requestService: RequestService) { }

    private setSession(response): void {
        response = (response.json) ? response.json() : JSON.parse(response);
        const profiles = (response.profiles) ? response.profiles : response;
        profiles.forEach((profile) => {
            if (this.features) {
                this.features = this.features.concat(profile.features);
            } else {
                this.features = profile.features;
            }
        });

        // remove duplicates
        this.features = Array.from(new Set(this.features));
        this.profiles = profiles;
    }

    private getProfile(): Promise<any> {
        return this.requestService.profilesUsingGET()
            .then((response) => {
                this.setSession(response);
            }).catch(() => {

            });
    }

    public getSession(): Promise<any> {
        return this.getProfile();
    }

    public hasFeature(feature: string): boolean {
        if (this.features) {
            return this.features.indexOf(feature.toUpperCase()) !== -1;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public getFullName(): string {
        if (this.profiles && this.profiles[0]) {
            return this.profiles[0].fullName;
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

The unit test:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ProfileService } from './profile.service';
import { RequestService } from '../shared/request.service';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

describe('ProfileService', () => {

    const mockData = JSON.stringify([
        {
            fullName: 'John Doe',
            features: ['FEATURE 1', 'FEATURE 2']
        },
        {
            fullName: 'Jane Seinhorst',
            features: ['FEATURE 3', 'FEATURE 4']
        }
    ]);

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                ProfileService,
                RequestService
            ],
            imports: [
                BrowserModule,
                SharedModule,
                FormsModule,
                HttpModule
            ]
        });
    });

    it('should be created', inject([ProfileService], (service: ProfileService) => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    it('should define public methods', inject([ProfileService], (service: ProfileService) => {
        expect(service.getFullName).toBeTruthy();
        expect(service.hasFeature).toBeTruthy();
        expect(service.getSession).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    it('should load the user\'s profile and set the correct features',
        inject(
            [ProfileService, RequestService],
            (service: ProfileService, requestService: RequestService) => {

        spyOn(requestService, 'ProfilesUsingGET').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(mockData));

        service.getSession()
            .then(() => {
                expect(service.hasFeature('feature 1')).toBe(true);
                expect(service.hasFeature('FEATURE 1')).toBe(true);
                expect(service.hasFeature('feature 2')).toBe(true);
                expect(service.hasFeature('feature 3')).toBe(true);
                expect(service.hasFeature('feature 4')).toBe(true);

                expect(service.hasFeature('feature 5')).toBe(false);
                expect(service.hasFeature('feature 0')).toBe(false);

                // second time its should be loaded from cache
                service.getSession()
                    .then(() => {
                        expect(service.hasFeature('feature 1')).toBe(true);
                        expect(service.hasFeature('FEATURE 1')).toBe(true);
                        expect(service.hasFeature('feature 2')).toBe(true);
                        expect(service.hasFeature('feature 3')).toBe(true);
                        expect(service.hasFeature('feature 4')).toBe(true);

                        expect(service.hasFeature('feature 5')).toBe(false);
                        expect(service.hasFeature('feature 0')).toBe(false);
                    });

            });

    }));

    it('should return the correct fullName',
        inject(
            [ProfileService, RequestService],
            (service: ProfileService, requestService: requestService) => {

        spyOn(requestService, 'ProfilesUsingGET').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(mockData));

        service.getSession()
            .then(() => {
                expect(service.getFullName()).toBe('John Doe');
            });

    }));

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5526 the issue described in the question was an Angular 4 bug. With an upgrade to Angular 5 the issue is resolved.